# Finding all uniq strings in a file

Tags: unix, awk, grep

If I have a file like so:

```
find,apple,strg_sf,RTR,hand,mountain,stuff_about
apple,find,not,here,key_board,
core,chip,pro_ces,
apple,core,strg_sf,RTR,key_board,not
```

and I want to output all the unique strings in the file so something like

output:

```
find,apple,strg_sf,RTR,hand,mountain,stuff_about,not,here,key_board,core,chip,pro_ces
```

`sort` and `uniq` seem to just output unique rows when I'm looking for unique strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use sort and uniq if you want:

```
$ <input.txt tr ',' '\n' | sort -u | paste -s -d , -
```

This may look a little odd, but it's a perfectly valid command line. :)

I've put the input redirection at the beginning to make the pipe a little more clear.

- `tr` translates commas to newlines.
- `sort -u` sorts and uniqs.
- `paste` assembles things back into a single line, delimited by commas.

Note that the output of this is SORTED, so it doesn't match the output you said you wanted.  If you want to uniq without sorting, a solution like this might work:

```
$ <input.txt tr ',' '\n' | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=","}!a[$0]++'
```

This has the advantage of using fewer pipes, at the cost of requiring your entire list to be loaded into an array in memory by awk in order to determine which lines are unique.  Note that a.s is, it doesn't print a newline at the end.